# Change URL on click of browser refresh button

Tags: .net, asp.net, browser-refresh

I have a login.aspx page. There is a validation in another page say FirstPage.aspx once login successful, and if the validation fails,page will be redirected back to **"login.aspx?status=false"**. Then the error message is assigned a label in Login.aspx page and it will be displayed. Now, the requirement is, if I click on browser's refresh button now, teh URL should get changed to "login.aspx".

How to achieve this. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can kind of do this (detect a page refresh) in a couple of way - see [Detecting Page Refreshes :: Using JavaScript on Client-Side](http://www.tedpavlic.com/post_detect_refresh_with_javascript.php).

The simplest approach seems to be to use hidden form variables.  Apparently form variables are maintained across page refreshes by most modern browsers, by updating the value of a hidden field with JavaScript we can take advantage of this to detect when the page is refreshed:

```
<input type="hidden" name="visited" value="" />

if( document.refreshForm.visited.value == "") {
    // This is a fresh page load
    document.refreshForm.visited.value = "1";
} else {
    // This is a page refresh
    // either redirect to login.aspx, or just update the page accordingly
}
```

You can either redirect the user when you detect a page refresh, or better would be to alter the appearance of the page accordingly (which prevents an extra refresh of the page)

Comment: The URL is not accessible.Is it possible for you to post the code snippet.